# VLookup Formula with Wildcard "*" Not Working Properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a formula which strips the prefix of a value i need to find in another workbook's table. This is returning `#N/A` but i don't understand why? The goal is to strip `ASM:` in workbook B, then find `John Smith` in Workbook A.

```
Workbook A              Workbook B
John Smith (245)        ASM: John Smith
```

Here is my formula which is not working:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&RIGHT($A$4,LEN($A$4)-5)&"*",'[SY2018 Direct-Inside Sales Quotas.xlsx]Yearly ASM Quotas (FULL)'!$A:$F,5,FALSE)
```

Comment: You are taking 5 characters off of `John Smith (245)` leaving `John Smith<space>`. Use `"*"&TRIM(RIGHT($A$4,LEN($A$4)-5))&"*"`

Comment: This doesn't work. I am stripping away `ASM:` in Workbook B then looking for anything that matches `John Smith` in workbook A. I can successfully strip the `ASM:` but i dont think the wildcard is working

Comment: Is that a non-breaking space between Smith and (245)? Did you copy the data from a web site?

Comment: It might be. I didn't create this workbook I haven't any idea from where the data originates

Comment: Hmmmm   DOH! Try LEFT instead of RIGHT (but still use TRIM).

Answer (score 1):

See @Jeeped's comment for the explaination

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&TRIM(RIGHT($A$4,LEN($A$4)-5))&"*",'[SY2018 Direct-Inside Sales Quotas.xlsx]Yearly ASM Quotas (FULL)'!$A:$F,5,FALSE)
```